# Use SPFx with react-router

Tags: spfx, spfx-webparts

I'm wondering how to handle multi-routes react webpart in SharePoint, since it's actually rendered inside a page and not run individually itself.
I tried to implement a simple webpart with some routes and receive this error

> [react-router] Location "/temp/workbench.html" did not match any routes

Please support me on working with multi-routes webpart

Below is my code in the ContactsWebPart.tsx (I changed from ts -> tsx)

```
export default class ContactsWebPart extends BaseClientSideWebPart<IContactsWebPartProps> {

public constructor(context: IWebPartContext) {
  super(context);
}

public render(){
    const element = (<Provider store={store}>
         <Router history={browserHistory}>
              <Route path="/" component={AlphabetScreen}>                                
                   <IndexRoute component={AlphabetScreen}/>
              </Route>            
              <Route>                
                  <IndexRoute component={SearchScreen}/>
                  <Route path="contacts/(:char)" component={SearchScreen}/>
              </Route>
         </Router>    
      </Provider>)

    ReactDom.render(element, this.domElement)
  }

  protected get propertyPaneSettings(): IPropertyPaneSettings {
    return {
      pages: [
        {
          header: {
            description: strings.PropertyPaneDescription
          },
          groups: [
            {
              groupName: strings.BasicGroupName,
              groupFields: [
                PropertyPaneTextField('description', {
                  label: strings.DescriptionFieldLabel
                })
              ]
            }
          ]
        }
      ]
    };
  }
```

Comment: Do you have a full solution for this? Would really like to see the code.
Have you done it with v4 api ? react-router-dom?

Comment: @user1983262 I no longer work on it so dont quite remember

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It turned out that I used `Link` component from `office-ui-fabric-react` and its `href` property does not work as `to` property of `Link` component from `react-router`

This will not work

```
import * as React from "react"
import {AlphabetChars} from "../constants"
import {Link} from "office-ui-fabric-react/lib/Link"

const AlphabetCharsList = ({alphabetChars}) => {
    return (
        <div>
          {
              alphabetChars.map((char) => 
              <div key={char.romaji}>
                <Link href={"/contacts/" + char.romaji}>{char.hiragana}/{char.romaji}</Link>
                <br/>
                </div>
              )
          }  
        </div>
    )
}

export default AlphabetCharsList
```

But this does!

```
import * as React from "react"
import {AlphabetChars} from "../constants"
import {Link} from "react-router"

const AlphabetCharsList = ({alphabetChars}) => {
    return (
        <div>
          {
              alphabetChars.map((char) => 
              <div key={char.romaji}>
                <Link to={"/contacts/" + char.romaji}>{char.hiragana}/{char.romaji}</Link>                    
                <br/>
                </div>
              )
          }  
        </div>
    )
}

export default AlphabetCharsList
```

Answer (score -1):

you can use createMemoryHistory

Comment: I tried but it work only for this route on first load `<Route path="/" component={AlphabetScreen}>                                
                   <IndexRoute component={AlphabetScreen}/>`. 
When I call to this route
 `<Route path="contacts/(:char)" component={SearchScreen}/>`, it will redirect to https://mysites/contacts/a for example, and of course it will not be loaded. I think it should be https://mysites/mypage/contacts/a

Comment: Here'shat works for me (its using redux as well):const store: Redux.Store<any> = configureStore({});
const history = createMemoryHistory(location);
const App: React.StatelessComponent<any> = () => (
  <Provider store={store}>
    <Router history={history}>
      {routes}
    </Router>
  </Provider>
);

Comment: Thank @russellg. It turned out that I used Link component from `office-ui-fabric-react` and its `href` property does not work as `to` property of Link component from `react-router`